# How to insert cyrillic characters in a sqlite table using fts3 in android

Tags: android, sqlite, utf-8, cyrillic

I have a sqlite database in my android app where all tables are virtual because i need a fast search over some whole tables. I'm also using the and extended class of SQLiteOpenHelper to open the my database.

Here an example of a table create I use:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE person USING fts3(firstName VARCHAR(50), lastName VARCHAR(50))
```

Everything works fine as long as every text I insert is in latin characters. Unfortunatly whenever I try to insert some cyrillic characters I get a SQLiteException near the cyrillic character which it says is a syntax error.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO person (firstName, lastName) VALUES ('John','Россия')

    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Россия":
 syntax-error: INSERT INTO person (firstName, lastName) VALUES ('John','Россия')
```

As far as I know SQLite uses utf-8 as standard.
I have already tried to do it without using fts3 (no virtual table), but the result is the same.

Could somebody help me to find out what I'm missing to insert cyrillic text into my database?